# Maximum Browser Width and Height On Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, width

Ive Googled and stackoverflowed since earlier on today and i just cant find a solution. I'm looking for a way using JQuery/JS to open up a webpage ive created with a maximized window. So on the page loading whichever browser the user is using, my webpage will be displayed as though the user has hit the maximise button on their browser, but automatically on load.

I need to make an interactive website which is best displayed maximised, any ideas? Btw im very new to building websites so any solution JS fiddle based or properly explained would be so much appreciated.

THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, JavaScript cannot change the window's size (including minimizing or maximizing it).

You can, however, open a new window set to a certain size - but not automatically - only in response to user interaction, like a click on the page (again, for security reasons).

I don't know what your site's content is - but if it isn't flexible enough to fit different screen sizes (like a game, maybe?) then your best bet from a user experience perspective may be to just put some text up somewhere on the page that says something like "Site best viewed in fullscreen". Or, if it is something like a game, maybe a nice big button on the homepage that says "Launch Game"?

Your *best* bet, however, is to have your content fit any screen size/shape. This is often called things like "responsive webdesign", and there's tons of info out there on how to design a website responsively, as well as how to implement said design.

Good luck!

Comment: Yea thank, but i already thought about using a link to open the window to a set size, ive got Jquery for thay but i really wanted a fully maxed out screen. Like with having a max screen for a video i know there are security issues so its not a thing you can really do with JS unless you are using an API or something. I can get the content to fit any screen with the browser but that involves using 100% height and it sucks because it resizes and looks odd. Thanks for trying anyway

Answer (score 0):

window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp